# Fonts are not applied when hosted in IIS

Tags: asp.net, css, iis-7, font-face

I have applied some fonts in my CSS. they are applied when I run the website from my visual studio. but when I host the website in IIS fonts are not applied.

I am using CSS3 property font-face to load font files.

I have Googled a lot but I did not find any solution for it.

Can any body help me here?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are facing the similar issue , try adding .woff and .svg extensions in IIS MIME Type.

By default, the MIME types in IIS are configured to deliver EOT (as used by IE) and TTF files. But WOFF (Firefox) and SVG (iPhone, iPad & others) will not be served.

Open IIS , go to your IIS Type section and Add following extension there. 
.woff  application/x-woff
.svg   image/svg+xml